# How to send POST login request to a rails api-only app using React?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a working rails RESTful api-only app.
I use Postman to consume that api. Now, to use the api the user have to login to `http://localhost:3002/authenticate` first by setting `content-type` to `application-json` in Header then Email and Password's value in body. After sending the **POST** request to the server I get `auth-token` as a `json` response. Then after successful login I have to pass that `auth-token` as a `Authorization` key in each **GET** request to get respective data.
Now, I want to build a UI for that back-end api as I learn `React js`. But till now all tutorials I could find was how to send GET requests without any authorization factor. And they are using axios, redux etc.

- Can any-one please guide me on where should I start or how to
  approach this problem?
- Do I necessarily have to use a third-party library for this purpose?
  If so which will be better axios or redux??
- Any beginner friendly tutorial link would be of tremendous help

Answer (score 0):

**How start**

[Securing React Redux Apps With JWT Tokens](https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/securing-react-redux-apps-with-jwt-tokens-fcfe81356ea0) - Rajaraodv explains how you get a jwt token and how to keep it in the front end app. I think this way will fits for you.

**Keep the auth-token**

Rajaraodv uses localStorage to keep the jwt token, you can use the same or keep directly in redux store, it's your choice, the best manner that fits you.

**Ajax call**

You can use Axios to make Ajax calls, or use fetchApi from the browser as Rajaraodv did, it's up to you.

**Explains**

"If so which will be better axios or redux??" these two libraries are totally different, each with it's own purpose.